# What is the opposite method of Any<T>

Tags: c#, linq

How can I check with Linq if a collection does not contain an object. I.E. The opposite of `Any<T>`.

I could invert the result with a `!` but for readability I wondered if there was a more better way to do this? Should I add the extension myself?

Comment: More readable then `!` ? `Contains`, `Exists` ?

Comment: Yeah, there's no `None<T>`. I often use such custom extensions for readability (for example I don't like the `!dictionary.ContainsKey(key)` syntax, so I implemented `dictionary.NoKey(key)` instead.

Comment: @Morawski: I've started using `ConcurrentDictionary`, because it's go the really handy `GetOrAdd` method, even when I don't need concurrency.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You can easily create a `None` extension method:

```
public static bool None<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    return !source.Any();
}

public static bool None<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
    return !source.Any(predicate);
}
```

Comment: I feel this would be a nice addition to standard Linq.

Comment: @Ivan, it's not in Linq itself, but it's [part](https://github.com/thomaslevesque/Linq.Extras/blob/master/Linq.Extras/None.cs) of my [Linq.Extras](https://github.com/thomaslevesque/Linq.Extras/) library

Answer (score 81):

The opposite of verifying that any (at least one) record matches a certain criteria would be verifying that all records do not match the criteria.

You didn't post your full example, but if you wanted the opposite of something like:

```
var isJohnFound = MyRecords.Any(x => x.FirstName == "John");
```

You could use:

```
var isJohnNotFound = MyRecords.All(x => x.FirstName != "John");
```

Comment: Just came across this today on Google, and while I agree with your approach, I typically use `var isJohnNotFound = !MyRecords.All(x => x.FirstName == "John");`

Comment: Of course, I goofed. When I do this it's not with a single field being checked. Usually it's more like `!MyRecords.All(x => InvalidNames.Any(n => n == x.Name));` So check every entry against a list of invalid names, only if none match will the result be true.

Comment: Please note that .All() returns true on empty sets. This is actually the behaviour I wanted, so I managed to switch from !Any(x => !x.condition) to .All(x => condition). 
Thanks guys

Answer (score 4):

Found this thread when I wanted to find out if a collection does not contain one object but I do **not** want to check that **all** objects in a collection match the given criteria. I ended up doing a check like this:

```
var exists = modifiedCustomers.Any(x => x.Key == item.Key);

if (!exists)
{
    continue;
}
```

Comment: This is under appreciated. In my understanding, ``All(? != ?)`` will check every single element, whereas ``!Any(? == ?)`` will only check until it finds the first match.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answers added, if you don't want to wrap `Any()` method you can implement `None()` as follows:

```
public static bool None<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) 
{
    if (source == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source)); }

    using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        return !enumerator.MoveNext();
    }
}

public static bool None<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
    if (source == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source)); }
    if (predicate == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(predicate)); }

    foreach (TSource item in source)
    {
        if (predicate(item))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

In addition to that for the parameterless overload you can apply `ICollection<T>` optimization, which actually does not exist in LINQ implemenetation.

```
ICollection<TSource> collection = source as ICollection<TSource>;
if (collection != null) { return collection.Count == 0; }
```