# Java noneMatch() equivalent in C# Linq

Tags: c#, linq

What's the equivalent of this Java sample in C# using Linq?

```
int[] someArray(int[] arr1, int[] arr2)
{
    return Arrays.stream(arr1).filter(a->Arrays.stream(arr2).noneMatch(i->i == a)).toArray();
}
```

Comment: Removing the `java` tag because your question is not about `java`.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/8741439

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not really familiar with Java 8 Streams, but isn't `noneMatch()` equivalent to `!anyMatch()`?

You can use `IEnumerable.Any()` and negate it's result to get what you want:

```
int[] SomeArray(int[] arr1, int[] arr2)
{
    return arr1.Where(a1 => !arr2.Any(a2 => a2 == a1)).ToArray();
}
```

You could also negate the inner condition and use `All`:

```
int[] SomeArray(int[] arr1, int[] arr2)
{
    return arr1.Where(a1 => arr2.All(a2 => a2 != a1)).ToArray();
}
```